# Designing WP7 App

Tags: windows-phone-7, windows-phone-7.1, windows-phone, windows-phone-7.1.1

I have made one windows phone based application. i want some designing ideas from you wp7 people.how can we apply styles,transparent background or the design which suits wp7 app. may i have some links which provides snaps for good designed apps. please help

Comment: I gave the -1. Despite giving a response (see below) this question does not fit stack overflow guidelines because you're not asking a specific question that has a specific answer. See the FAQ section for more information. It's not a bad question, and it's nothing personal, just not the right place for this kind of question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

MSDN user experience guidelines are pretty good, [User Experience Design Guidelines for Windows Phone](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh202915%28v=VS.92%29.aspx).

Also, it helps to install some popular apps from the marketplace and study their design.

Answer (score 2):

One app that jumps to my mind when talking about great use and adaption to the metro design, it's "Cocktail Flow". It has very well done implementations of many design cues for WP7. As special treats it has features like parallax effects controled via gyroscope.

You can find a free version [on the marketplace](http://www.windowsphone.com/de-DE/apps/ddd1ad08-d9d5-df11-a844-00237de2db9e/). Definitely worth a look.

Answer (score 0):

The **BEST** thing you can possibly do to get a good idea of how to build a great WP7 app is to own a Windows Phone, and use it as your primary phone.

Get used to the way the operating system flows. Download cool apps. As time goes on you begin to understand from the user's perspective what a "good" app looks (and more importantly) *feels* like. It's a hard thing to nail down in a "user experience" spec. I find that a lot of people who set off to build a WP7 app do so before understanding how apps are supposed to behave on the platform. It is *vital* that you understand how users expect applications on the windows phone to operate. If you use a windows phone for a good 3-4 months, and really make an effort of butting it through the steps, it will be hard to walk away from that experience without a very clear idea of what a "good" application looks like for the windows phone.

That being said, and while I honestly don't believe that there are any short cuts to good design for the windows phone, I highly recommend downloading the following apps, and playing around with them to get a feel for "good" UI:

- Wordament
- Cocktail Flow (previously mentioned)
- Twitter
- Spotify
- Yelp
- Any of the built in applications (Office, Zune, Internet Explorer)

The above are good to start with, but again, you're really not going to understand it unless you live and breath it everyday for at least a few months.